# Putting output into SQL table

Tags: sed, awk, database, sql

I am trying to convert the output of

```
ps awux
```

into 11 fields with the headers eliminated and then importing that output into an existing table in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in $(ps auwx | sed -e 's/\ \+/\",\"/g'); do
    echo "insert into tbl_name values(\"$line\")"; 
done | mysql
```

Comment: have to be more careful when the command column contains whitespace

Comment: @glennjackman Yup...that would break things, wouldn't it.  Short of a messy `awk` script you're probably going to have to break this out into a real scripting language.

Comment: Also, don't read lines with "for": http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first line with `sed 1d`

You can create the values list with

```
sql=$( 
    echo "$line" | sed "
    s/'/''/g
    s/[[:space:]]\+/','/   # 1
    s/[[:space:]]\+/','/   # 2
    s/[[:space:]]\+/','/   # 3
    s/[[:space:]]\+/','/   # 4
    s/[[:space:]]\+/','/   # 5
    s/[[:space:]]\+/','/   # 6
    s/[[:space:]]\+/','/   # 7
    s/[[:space:]]\+/','/   # 8
    s/[[:space:]]\+/','/   # 9
    s/[[:space:]]\+/','/   # 10
    s/^/INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('/
    s/$/');/
    "
)
```